# One attribute storing likle array

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Please I really discouraged,
Is it possible to make a single entity like array attribute?
For example :
entity = person
attribute = courses
And the entity able to contain a few courses(attribute).

i have a many persons, and i need storing many courses on one person
and i don't know where to store them, and how store them

and after to get the specific person and show the all courses...

Comment: i have a many persons, and i need storing many courses on one person
and i don't know where to store them, and how store them 

and after to get the specific person and show the all courses...

Answer (score 2):

It would be a more common design to make both person and course entities and then have a many-to-many relationship between them.  That way, if something about a course changes, you don't have to make the change in every person's array.